# Multiple domains for different language, best way to arrange?

Tags: .htaccess, dns

I have a site (let's call it finnish.com). I bought another domain, english.com. The idea is to have multilingual website. The sites are exactly same, but they obiously need language-specific information. I'm currently looking for the best way to do this. Probably it's htaccess. This is what I've tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule header.php$ header.php?lang=en [L]
```

However, this works as I manually visit header.php (which has the language-specific details), but if I include it through php, it doesn't work.

It would best, if selected files (no need to be dynamic; can be listed manually) would have a `$_GET`-attribute on another domain.

Any ideas?

Martti Laine

Comment: I guess all major CMSs have the ability to manage this. Why reinvent the wheel when you have a site that isn't built for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether it's what you need, but why not use `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]` to find out which domain the file is addressed under? Then you could switch languages automatically.